# composing external @context in JSON-LD

Tags: json-ld

I've read through the doc and spec of JSON-LD and JSON-LD-API (and might as well have missed something).

I found that the local context of an object node may be composed by defining "@context: [.., .., ...]" as an array of multiple context definitions (some of which may be inlined, others may be external references). I also found that referencing an "external context" assumes the corresponding IRI reference resolves to a JSON-LD document with an expected @context definition in its root object node, which is to be used in place of the original reference to the "external context".

My question is: Is it valid (or reasonable, or implied), that the referenced @context in the remote JSON-LD document may also be composite (just like an ordinary local @context), or is a referenced external context restricted to being a *definite* context entity (i.e. either a local XOR external definition, i.e. NOT an *array* of many context definitions)?

(This question is probably directed towards the authors of the JSON-LD standard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A remote context is not restricted in any way which means that it can contain references to other contexts.