# External @context files for "composite" JSON objects?

Tags: rdf, json-ld, linked-data

**TL;DR:**

Given that:

- *Ca* is a JSON-LD `@context` file that describes JSON object A;
- *Cb* is a JSON-LD `@context` file that describes JSON object B;
- Every B JSON object contains an element whose assigned value is an A object;

1) How can/should this relationship between A and B be described in *Cb*? Is it a `@type`, an `@id`, an inner `@context`?

2) If an A object, when used as value in a B object, could *also* mean something described in a vocabulary such as *schema.org*, how should *both* relationships of A be described in *Cb*?

---

Some users of my API don´t want metadata at all, so I have pure JSON as default response format, and I would like to use JSON-LD @context files as a simple syntactic and semantic schema, should users want one, according to https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#interpreting-json-as-json-ld .

If I got it correctly, if I have a simple data structure which uses primitive types, the JSON-LD file will be something simple -- like this, for defining a certain part of an event:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "schema": "http://schema.org/docs/schema_org_rdfa.html",
    "xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#",
    "titulo": {
      "@id": "schema:name",
      "@type": "xsd:string"
    },
    "dataHoraInicio": {
      "@id": "schema:startDate",
      "@type": "xsd:dateTime"
    },
    "dataHoraFim": {
      "@id": "schema:endDate",
      "@type": "xsd:dateTime"
    }
  }
}
```

But some of my JSON structures have some other structures embedded into them. In other words: in some of my JSON structures, there are elements which receive as values some other of my API´s JSON structures. The representation of a speech, for example, might have as part of it an element named "momento", and its value would be the above mentioned structure which represents a part of an event.

If so, how should I represent this "composition" relation between entities in an external JSON-LD @context file? How should I describe what "momento" is and the kind of value it receives in the JSON-LD @context file?

Browsing other questions here, I found that there is no problem in [an external @context being referred to by another @context file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27004011/composing-external-context-in-json-ld). But do I have to use the other file´s URL as the value for `@id`? Or for `@type`? Or in a completely different way than that used for the primitive datatypes?

And what if some of these nested/referred data structures should *also* be classified with a vocabulary term? For example, I would like to express that "momento" can be understood as schema.org´s "Event", and at the same time I would like to express that the object it takes as value is described in another JSON-LD file.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Just a note about your example: I think you want to use `"schema": "http://schema.org/"` instead. Schema.org’s `name` property has the URI `http://schema.org/name`, not `http://schema.org/docs/schema_org_rdfa.htmlname`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, unor. Do you know whether references to schema.org/ will "naturally work" with RDF processors?